# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{2\leq i < j \leq n} \log_i j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate:
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{2\leq i < j \leq n} \log_i j$$

I guess the first step is to write the summand as $\dfrac{\log j}{\log i}$, but I don't know how to proceed afterwards, it's probably some tricky idea to break it into  more manageable sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\to\infty$ we can replace the double sum by a double integral and compute

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\int_1^n\mathrm dx\int_x^n\mathrm dy\frac{\log y}{\log x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\int_1^n\mathrm dx\frac{n\log n-n-x\log x+x}{\log x}\;.
$$

Since $\int\frac1{\log x}\mathrm dx\sim\frac x{\log x}$, the first term yields $1$. The third term yields $-\frac12$. The second and fourth term go to zero, so the overall limit is $\frac12$.